# ReferrerId too short

Tags: opayo

referrerId on sagepay documentation is definited as not mandatory, but we receive always error 'referrer id too short'. We tried to pass it null or valorized with vendor name but we received always the same error in both cases.

Anyone knows why and how to resolve this problem? 
We are using prolcol 3.00 and error is on sagepay test environment.

Comment: Speak to sage directly.

Comment: yours is great help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from your string completely. If the field is submitted then Sage Pay will try to validate it's contents and return an error if it doesn't meet their requirements. The ReferrerID is only used to validate the Sage Pay partner which has referred the Sage Pay user.

Answer (score 0):

The referrer ID is a UUID string that will be allocated to your referrer (i.e. reseller) account, if you have one. It will be 36 characters long.

It is optional, so leave it out *completely* if you are not using it. It must be either 36 characters long, or not present at all. Sage Pay always requires optional fields to be left out when they don't contain any data.

You cannot just make up your own referrer IDs either. It must be one that Sage Pay has created and allocated to a reseller. This is mine (with blocks moved around to make it invalid - though I would love you to use my real referrer ID, it is probably well against SO TOS, so this one just gives a feel for what it looks like):

```
EB478671-4119-3F7A-A091-9E59464FB80C
```

@Neil-Collier got this answer first, and I recommend that he be marked as the correct answer - I'm adding minor details.